# Linecache adding an extra line to the line that i get

Tags: python, lines, getline, linecache

When i try to get a line using linecache in python.

```
loginpass = raw_input("> ")
if loginpass == linecache.getline('Password.txt', 1):
```

The line that it gets always returns with an extra line. 
So if line one is

```
"Test"
```

It returns

```
"Test
"
```

It worked earlier in the code but anything after that it adds that line after it.

Comment: Please do not use `linecache` to read files, as the documentation says, it is meant only for efficiently fetching lines of Python source code for display in tracebacks.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal; reading lines from a file includes the line-ending newline character. Just strip it off:

```
linecache.getline('Password.txt', 1).rstrip('\n')
```

I'm more concerned that you're storing passwords in plain text, though....